# What is this pumping nozzle called?

Tags: maintenance, tire, wheels, pump

My local bike shop have one of these green nozzles that anyone can use to pump their bike. They say that only companies can buy those, but I would really like such for my blue compressor.

What I like about this type is that there is no tap that needs to be flipped like so [many pumps have](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61EqrVfC0lL._SL1500_.jpg).

Does anyone know what such nozzle is called and perhaps online shops that allow for end users to buy such?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a standard [schrader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve) head.  Locking heads are only needed for hand- or foot-pumps as you can't secure the head on while pumping the pump manually.

Any well-stocked automobile parts store will have a schrader head for an air-compressor that doesn't require a locking head.  Schrader valves are the same valves used on your automobile tire.

For example, my local part supply store has this [kit](http://www.harborfreight.com/20-Piece-Air-Compressor-Starter-Kit-68191.html) for $14.  Just walk into a car parts store and ask for the tire-inflation attachment for your compressor.

[image]

Note that if your bike has a presta or dunlop valve, you'll need either an adapter or a different head.

Also, be careful when using an electric air compressor to inflate your tires. Your bike tires are very low-volume and it's easy to over-inflate and burst them. Set the pressure on the compressor as low as you can and don't trust the low pressure cut-off to react quick enough to save your tire.

In this case, your specific compressor (the Scheppach HC16w) has a maximum pressure of 8 bar (around 116 psi) and does not have a storage air-tank. Be careful when pumping up low-pressure tires (like regular bicycle tires) so that you don't over inflate them.  You may have trouble inflating racing or road bike tires (100 psi+) and may have to top them off with a track pump.

Comment: That said I would advise against using a motor driven compressor to inflate bicycle tyres as the pressure might only fit MTBs and be too low for racing tyres.

Comment: Something useful to have might be something like Park Tool INF-1 so you can carefully set the pressures. Though in many cases, faffing around with an air compressor for one bike is probably slower than just using a track pump.

Comment: I have that kit, which I use with my Harbor Freight air tank. Stick with the simple stuff and you can get good stuff from them :)

Comment: Fat tires are the exception to that Batman....they take forever.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "[schrader chuck](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=schrader%20chuck)" or "[schrader head](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=schrader%20head)", and take your pick. If you want one locally. any auto parts store should have a couple to choose from.

Alternatively, if you need a presta head, just switch the search terms. [Silca](http://silca.cc/) makes a couple of popular ones.